# Replacing the first n values of each R dataframe column according to function

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to compare a "regular" data-set to a contaminated one, however I'm having trouble creating the contaminated data-set

Each list contains 25 data-frames, to each corresponding a size n; each data-frame contain m=850 samples of size n = {100, 200, ..., 2500} of an exponential distribution

I have tried replacing the first n/4 items of each sample for each data-frame.

The current way I am doing it adds extra entries to the contaminated data-frames, which I do not want - I merely wish to replace them.
However, if I switch c(j) with c(1:n/4), an error pops up saying replacement has 25 rows, data has 100.

What could I do better?

```
set.seed(915)

n_lst <- seq(from = 100, to = 2500, by=100)

m_lst <- seq(from=1, to=850, by=1)

l = list()

lCont = list()

i=1

for (n in n_lst) {

l[[i]] = lCont[[i]] = data.frame(replicate(850, rexp(n, 0.73)))

for (j in m_lst) {

lCont[[i]][c(j), c(1:n/4)] = rexp(n/4, 0.01)
}
i <-i+1
}
```

Bellow are the original list and the contaminated list (sorry about the formatting issues I was having trouble with the formatting verification)

[Original List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag3TM.png)
[Contaminated List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqPvb.png)

Comment: You have your rows and columns switched, you need `lCont[[i]][1:(n / 4), j]`. That is, `data[rows, columns]`. Also note that (a) all your `c()`s are unnecessary, and (b) you need parentheses in `1:(n / 4)`. (Compare `1:8/4` with `1:(8/4)` in your console.)

Comment: That was exactly it! Thank you so much, and also for the c() and parentheses clarification 
(Do you know how to mark a question as answered, by the way? The FAQ only mentions green-checking "answers", not comments, even though it was your comment that helped me out)

Comment: I'll post my comment as an answer so it can accepted.

Comment: Bless your heart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are indexing using `[columns, rows]`, which is backwards. R indexes data frames and matrices as `[rows, columns]`. Switching to `lCont[[i]][1:(n / 4), j]` will solve that.

Also note that `:` comes early in R's order of operations, you want `1:(n / 4)`, not `1:n / 4`.

And a last comment, `c()` is only needed if you're combining more than one thing, like `c(1:5, 12)`. `c(j)` is a long way to write `j`.